# How to plot glm model coefficients with abline in R?

Tags: r, plot, glm

I'm struggling to plot the cofficients of an glm model using `abline`. Lets take this simple 2D example:

```
d <- iris[51:150, c(3:4,5)]
d[,3] <- factor(d[,3])
plot(d[,1:2], col=d[,3])
```

[image: The data]

The glm model yields 4 coefficients:

```
m <- glm(formula = Species~Petal.Length*Petal.Width, data = d, family = "binomial")
m$coefficients
# (Intercept)             Petal.Length              Petal.Width Petal.Length:Petal.Width 
#  -131.23813                 22.93553                 63.63527                -10.63606
```

How to plot those with a simple `abline`?

Comment: What do you expect `abline` to plot there?

Comment: Two problems: `abline` is only useful when there are two coefficients, slope and intercept, and with a GLM will show the fit in the transformed scale, not the response scale you are interested in. Solution is to make predictions and plot these.

Comment: @Roland I aimed for plotting the decision boundary directly from the coefficients. @ RichardTelford OK, this explains why using the coefficients directly is not possible - thx for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Binomial models are usually not set up like this. You usually will have a single 0|1 response variable (i.e. predict whether a sample in a single species). Maybe because you only have 2 species included in your model, it still seems to work (this is not that case when all 3 spp are included).
The second trick is to predict `type="response"` and round these values to get discrete predictions:

```
d$pred <- factor(levels(d[,3])[round(predict(m, type="response"))+1])
plot(d[,1:2], col=d[,3])
points(d[,1:2], col=d$pred, pch=4)
```

[image]

here I've added an "X" for the predictions. If color is the same, then the prediction was correct. I count 5 samples where the prediction was incorrect.